# MySQL Query executing twice

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning everyone :)

I'm a newbie here, i have a problem and can't solve it by myself with a simple query that is executing twice on my db, i can't understand why  ...

Can you check with me please what is wrong ?

My request is an ' INSERT INTO ' request , and it create two rows in database, one empty and one filled correctly.

Here is my code :

```
    <?php
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "stocksmasques";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

if (isset($_POST['operation']) && isset($_POST['value']) && isset($_POST['stock'])) {
    $operation = $_POST['operation'];
    $value = intval($_POST['value']);
    $stock = $_POST['stock'];
    $date = strval(date('d/m/Y'));
}

switch ($operation) {
    case "increment":
        $newStock = $stock + $value;
        echo "Le stock est mis a jour :".$newStock." ";
        break;
    case "decrement":
        $newStock = $stock - $value;
        echo "Le stock est mis a jour :".$newStock." ";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Le stock reste inchangé :".$stock." ";
}

$setNewStock = $dbh->query("UPDATE stock SET stock ='$newStock'");

$makeLog = $dbh->query("INSERT INTO logs (log, day) VALUES ('$newStock','$date')");

?>

<form action="index.php">
    <button type="submit">Retour</button>
</form>
```

---

The problem occurs with the request $makeLog

Comment: There is no evidence that the INSERT statement is being called twice. Do you have any code beneath the $makeLog line?

Comment: Should the close } for the first `if` enclose all of the insert logic?  At the moment it looks as though it will run every time the page is loaded.

Comment: Hello :) Thanks for your responses , thank to all of you, @NigelRen you was right !! In the beginning when i tested that my forms works well i created this " if " and checked these variables with a var_dump, but when i continued my code i forgot to write it in inside the if ! So it was executing twice, i don't know why but i solved my issue.